Nginx: 502 ошибка при попытке открыть сайт
Раскрыл сервер, nginx + php + mysql
Добавил сайт, простой скрипт. Все открывает, все читает...
Добавил временный домен в свой системный файл на ip адрес сервера.
Все работает, сайт открывает, php запускается. Все работает...
Залил свой сайт на сервер, настроил, работает. Только вот при попытке открыть сайт выдает 502 ошибку.
Весь день просидел, так и не разобрался в чем тут дело. В интене нет конкретного решения, что вызывает данную ошибку. Поэтому я тут...
В логах nginx, ошибки в основном на заранее не объявленные переменные,  они никак не могли вызвать ошибку...
Одна из последних, которую точно не понимаю...
2024/12/19 18:33:43 [error] 4075#4075: *1 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, client: 95.106.172.144, server: testss.ru, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock:", host: "testss.ru"

Далее мой конфиг
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 10000;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 1500M;

    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

И конфиг на сам сайт
server {
    server_name testss.ru;
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/testss.ru;
    index index.php;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    ##################################################################
    #### Перенаправляем с wwww на без
    ##################################################################
    if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*)$) {
        return 301 $scheme://$server_name$request_uri;
    }


    location ~* ^/faq-(help)$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?do=u&po=$1;  
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
        # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    location /pma {
        alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;
        }
    }
}

Все конфиги и настройки, по большей части дефолтные.
Что необходимо попытаться поправить, чтобы сайт заработал, не выдавал 502

Что интересно, когда включаю вывод ошибок в php

ini_set('display_errors', 1); Сайт подгружает, html страницу выдает и ошибки соответственно отображает. А 502 ошибки нет...

Надо увеличить fastcgi_buffer_size https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_buffer_size

Сработало, вопрос в том, есть ли возможность узнать какое значение будет оптимальным? Сейчас выставил 4 32k

Просто как пальцем в небо получается...

Надо смотреть какого размера заголовки вы отдаёте из php
